# Inserir texto fixo em Textarea

Tags: asp

Estou fazendo um formulário em uma página ASP3 que tem que trazer um texto fixo no Textarea.
Esse texto não pode ser alterado e oque o usuário digitar abaixo dele tem que salvar no banco sem esse texto fixo.

Alguém já fez algo assim?

Comment: Por que não fazer dois campos, um com os dados fixos e outro onde ele pode digitar e depois concatena os dois?

Comment: O que tiver dentro do textarea será enviado. Vc não pode fazer um replace no ASP do texto fixo removendo-o?

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção é submeter somente o conteúdo do textarea ao clicar em um botão pode ser feito do seguinte modo

```js
function myFunction() {

var texto=document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

console.log(texto);
}
```

```css
div.textarea-container {
   border: solid 1px #808080;
   overflow: auto;
   width: 400px;
   padding: 2px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
}

div.textarea-container textarea {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   overflow: auto;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-container" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextarea').focus()">
    <div id="txtFixo">Textarea com value que não da pra mudar.<br>Qual é a cor do cavalo branco do Napoleão? </div>
    <textarea id="myTextarea" style="width:400px; font-size:16px; height:100px; border-color:lightgray;" placeholder="Responda aqui" required></textarea>
</div>

<button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Cara é exatamente isso que eu precisava fazer.
Muito obrigado deu certinho.
E é bom que agora eu entendi como fazer e se aparacer algo semelhante nas próximas vezes eu já saberei como adaptar.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro a propriedade placeholder, inserindo o texto que você deseja.
Exemplo:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Texto temporário"></textarea>
```

Porém, ao começar a digitar esse texto irá sumir.
Se você deseja deixar um texto à vista, sugiro colocá-lo acima ou abaixo do textarea.

Ou pode ser utilizado dois componentes, sendo um desabilitado: (sugestão do Ricardo Pontual)

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="50" disabled>Digite seu texto</textarea>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sim mas ele ficará em 2 textareas. Tem que ser em um único. Existe a possibilidade de travar o texto dentro  no topo e ele não ir pro banco depois.

Comment: Eu entendi o que você precisa... mas não tem como. O textarea é um componente que não aceita parte de um texto editável e outra parte não editável. O que daria para fazer é algo em JavaScript para que a cada caractere inserido ele conte, e se baixar para menos da quantidade que considere o texto fixo, ele não permita apagar. Ao enviar para o banco, pegar a partir da posição que se deseja e enviar... seria uma "gambiarra" usando JavaScript para conseguir isso, rsrs.

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão usando JavaScript. Envolva o `textarea` em um elemento `<span>` com `overflow: hidden` e crie também outro `span` após o `textarea` com o texto fixo que deseja, e coloque uma classe nele, desta forma:

```
<span style="overflow: hidden;">
   <textarea style="width: 400px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;"></textarea>
   <span class="textofixo">Texto fixo, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
</span>
```

No CSS coloque o estilo da classe e do `span`:

```
<style>
span{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.textofixo{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Inclua este JavaScript na página:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var area = document.querySelector("textarea");
   var tFixo = document.querySelector(".textofixo");
   var tFixoHeight = tFixo.offsetHeight;
   area.style.paddingTop = tFixoHeight+"px";

   tFixo.onclick = function(){ area.focus() };

   area.oninput = function(){
      if (this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight){
         tFixo.style.top = -(this.scrollHeight-this.clientHeight)+"px";
      }else{
         tFixo.style.top = "0";
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

O `span` com o texto fixo será posicionado em cima do `textarea` e o JavaScript irá ajustar o espaçamento superior (*padding-top*) do campo de acordo com a altura do `span` que contém o texto fixo. Caso haja *scroll* no campo, o `span` irá subir também, simulando como se ele fosse parte do `textarea`.

O evento `onclick` aplicado ao `span` irá forçar o foco para o `textarea`.

**Veja em funcionamento:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var area = document.querySelector("textarea");
   var tFixo = document.querySelector(".textofixo");
   var tFixoHeight = tFixo.offsetHeight;
   area.style.paddingTop = tFixoHeight+"px";
   
   tFixo.onclick = function(){ area.focus() };
   
   area.oninput = function(){
      tFixo.style.top = this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight ?
         -(this.scrollHeight-this.clientHeight)+"px" :
         "0";
   }
});
```

```css
textarea, .textofixo {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 14px;
}


/* códigos necessários abaixo */
span{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.textofixo{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span style="overflow: hidden;">
   <textarea style="width: 400px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;"></textarea>
   <span class="textofixo">Texto fixo, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu pensei no **placeholder**, só que o texto não pode sumir, o usuário tem que digitar abaixo dele.